# Получает ли редактор фидбек, если его правка отклонена одним из участников, но в общем является принятой?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предлагаемые-правки

Есть [утвержденная правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/115673), принятая голосами двух против одного.
Интересно, получает ли автор правки сообщение, которое было добавлено при отклонении? Изменилось ли что-нибудь в плане уведомления, если бы правку не утвердили?

Comment: нет не получает, в принципе вроде ничего не получает даже если правку полностью отклонили

Comment: @Grundy печаль.

Comment: @Grundy, оформите в виде ответа, пожалуйста

Comment: @VenZell, эм, я бы подождал кого-нибудь кто точно скажет.

Comment: @Grundy сколько ждать будем?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2110/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: @alexolut, ну вот, это ж дубликат :-) предлагаю закрыть :)

Comment: @Grundy я не против, но в том вопросе так и нет ответа почему “так-задумано”

Comment: @alexolut, ну на это уж точно вряд ли кто ответит :-) можно попробовать @Nicolas спросить`

Comment: @Grundy на него одного и надежда:)